# How can I perform a HTTP DELETE request with body?

Tags: android, rest, http, http-delete

I want to perform a HTTP DELETE request with a xml in the body (not a form). How can I perform this HTTP DELETE request?

I tried with [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) but [there are some limitations with it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9100776/842697).

I tried with the apache's [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) too. But I don't know how to send the xml without the structure of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Well in the REST based api http request body is supported ..But i didn't find it anywhere implemented the request body for delete.Hmm interesting

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpDelete with body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body)

Comment: @WebnetMobile, It's not a duplicate. [HttpDelete with body](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3820549/842697) solves the problem if you want send a ````application/x-www-form-urlencoded```` structure but doesn't work with raw data (like a xml).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpDelete with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773338/httpdelete-with-body)

Answer (score 4):

This code will make it:

```
try {
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonArray.toString());
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpDeleteWithBody httpDeleteWithBody = new HttpDeleteWithBody("http://10.17.1.72:8080/contacts");
        httpDeleteWithBody.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpDeleteWithBody);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To access the response you can simply do: `response.getStatusLine();`

And here is the HttpDeleteWithBody class definition: [HttpDeleteWithBody](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/290)

Answer (score 3):

why not do this with HttpClient

```
class MyDelete extends HttpPost{
    public MyDelete(String url){
        super(url);
    }
    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "DELETE";
    }

}
```

it works well.